# Split table if exceeded and duplicate the table header- iTextSharp - C#

Tags: c#, itext

I would like to know if there is a way to detect if the last row in a table is exceeded the page and if so write it on the next page and write the table header to the next page as well.

I don't want to use `table.KeepTogether = true;` because if the table is longer than 1 page it just move the exceeded rows to the next page without the header.

The table does not start from the beginning of the page, so using the `onStartPage()` event is not good.

This is how it looks when the table is exceeded 1 page:[image]

Hope that someone can help me here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want the repeating header functionality as described in the [HeaderFooter1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=86) example. For the corresponding C# examples, see http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04

For instance, if `table` is an instance of the `PdfPTable` class and the first row needs to be repeated when the table is split in two, then you need to add this line:

```
table.HeaderRows = 1;
```

Now the first row will be repeated automatically.